# Extracting information according to the matching information from external workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to pull information from an external workbook given the matching Project IDs from 2 different workbooks.

For example if Workbook A consists of Project ID `130021A` and Workbook B contains the same Project ID then Workbook A will pull the information of that Project ID from workbook B.

The Code below only works for a certain range of Project IDs. However I need to go through all the Project IDs in workbook A and workbook B.

```
Sub AAA()

If Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value = _
        Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value Then
   Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value = _
        Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
End If
End Sub
```

How can I fix this to get all IDs?

Comment: Your script only works when the exact same cells match. You might want to look into using LOOPS, so that you check in all cells for a match, not only the same cell in a different workbook.

Comment: Can you show me some codings that i could use for the loop? I am very new to VBA thus I am not sure of how to exactly use the loop method @Luuklag

Comment: you could take a look here: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work for you. I haven't ran or debugged it, but if you find any errors let us know, and probably someone will be able to help out.

```
Dim row as integer
Dim row1 as integer
Dim totalrowss as integer 'source rows
Dim totalrowsd as integer 'destination rows
Dim wkbs as Workbook 'source workbook
Dim wkbd as Workbook 'destination workbook
Dim wkss as Worksheet 'source worksheet
Dim wksd as Worksheet 'destination worksheet

Set wkbs = workbooks("Source.xlsm")
Set wkbd = workbooks("Target.xlsm")
Set wkss = wkbs.worksheets("Sheet2")
Set wksd = wkbd.worksheets("Sheet1")

totalrowss = wkss.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
totalrowsd = wksd.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For row = 2 to totalrowss
    For row1 = 2 to totalrowsd
        If wkss.Cells(row, 1) = wksd.Cells(row1, 1) Then
            wksd.Cells(row1, 3) = wkss.Cells(row, 2)
            'Exit for              'Remove ' before Exit if only one match can exist
        End if
    Next row1
Next row
```